# How to find the previous row using timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Starting with a table with a `timestamp` and a (geographical) `point`, data is received and populated unordered (so, identity column is not a good option).
I need to perform a calculation with information from the immediate previous row in time, (sorted by `timestamp`), then taking the time and the `point` to calculate the segment speed.

The next example assume I have a unique id on table named [spot].

```
SELECT point.STDistance(
       (SELECT point FROM [Spot] WHERE id=(s.id + 1)))
        / datediff(ss,[timestamp], 
            (SELECT [timestamp] FROM [Spot] where id=(s.id + 1)))
FROM [Spot] s WHERE id= 21927
```

Any better proposal?

Comment: 'timestamp': a user column with the sample time. Samples are sent not in 'time' order.

Answer (score 0):

if the id could help you to find the previous row i suggest you not using timestamp to find it

try join:

```
select t2.point/datediff(ss,t1.timestamp,t2.timestamp)
from spot t1
join spot t2
on t1.id = t2.id-1
```

but i can't really read your query it's a little bit messy.so i done this with my own understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I need to perform a calculation with information from the immediate previous row in time, (sorted by timestamp)...below is one way to calculate immediate previous row

```
 with cte
    as
    (select timestamp,max(timestamp) over(partition by timestamp 
                                   order by timestamp
                                   rows between unbounded preceeding and current row) as maxrow
   from table
    )
```

then calculate datediff..

```
select point/datediff(ss,cte.timestamp,cte.maxrow) from 
cte c
join
table t on
t.timestamp.cte.timestamp
```

You should also add a case to make sure you don't get divide by zero exception ,some thing like below..

```
select case when datediff(ss,cte.timestamp,cte.maxrow)=0 then 0
else point/datediff(ss,cte.timestamp,cte.maxrow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Window Functions:

```
select ... datediff(ss, lag(timestamp) over(order by timestamp), timestamp) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few caveats, this is the way works for me:

```
  DECLARE @tmp table(
        id int identity(1,1), 
        [point] geography, 
        [timestamp] datetime)

  INSERT @tmp  
    SELECT[point],[timestamp] from [Spot] order by [timestamp] desc

   SELECT p1.[point],p1.[timestamp],p2.[point],
    p2.[timestamp],
    p1.point.STDistance(p2.point),
    DATEDIFF(s,p2.[timestamp],p1.[timestamp]) 
  FROM @tmp p1 left join @tmp p2 on p1.id=p2.id-1
```

A join between the current row and the next row works and get the expected result.